# Message Queue Where Messages Can Be Filtered By Tags

Tags: message-queue

I'm in need of a message queue where I can associate messages with tags and receive only the messages that are associated with a certain tag.

For example let's say that `{id:1, tags: "tag1", "tag2"}` is a message with id **1** and associated with tags "**tag1**" and "**tag2**". So I would like the receive **1** when I ask for "**tag1**" or "**tag2**" from the queue but not for "**tag3**".

I also need this feature to support one-time delivery, which means when I receive the message above it won't be served again when asked for **tag1** or **tag2** (at least within the visibility timeout)

An MQ which enables filtering messages with a user-defined property would also work; but it should guarantee a one-time delivery of the message. So routing in AMQP (such as in RabbitMQ) would not work for me, since I believe it creates a copy of the message in each queue.

I've investigated several MQ implementations (RabbitMQ, ActiveMQ, SQS, MSMQ etc.) but failed to find an implementation of this feature. Is there an MQ which supports this type message filtering?

Comment: if your message do not have **tag3** you will not receive it, you can explore XPath to filter messages http://activemq.apache.org/selectors.html

Comment: if you receive and consume a message there is no reasons to receive it again

Comment: @HassenBennour Yes, consuming a message only one time is exactly what I want. I will play with Xpath selectors to see that if it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Since you were looking at RabbitMQ, ActiveMQ, SQS, MSMQ you may be also interested to check out [**ZeroMQ**](http://zeromq.org/), [**nanomsg**](http://nanomsg.org/index.html) or [**YAMI4**](http://www.inspirel.com/yami4/).

They have PUB/SUB mechanism with the filtering capabilities on the client side.
The client could receive messages with a particular tag.

Listening to many tags could be arranged by using dedicated threads or multiple connections.

PUB/SUB in [**ZeroMQ**](http://learning-0mq-with-pyzmq.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pyzmq/patterns/pubsub.html)

PUB/SUB in [**nanomsg**](http://nanomsg.org/v1.0.0/nn_pubsub.7.html)

PUB/SUB in [**YAMI4**](http://www.inspirel.com/yami4/book/6-4-2.html)

I use nanomsg in the production in C/C++ application and in Java app with Java bindings.